# How do I determine if the URI is a resource, content, or source site

Tags: c, wpf

I'm going to implement the business logic

1. Pass in a uriString
2. Create a URI
3. Determine whether the current URI is a resource, content, or source site
4. Get StreamResourceInfo

DemoCode:

```
//uriString is unknown
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
var resource = default(StreamResourceInfo);
//To distinguish the uri category
switch (GetCategory(uri))
{
//resource
case 0:
resource = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
break;
// content
case 1:
resource = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
break;
// source site
case 2:
resource = Application.GetRemoteStream(uri);
break;
default:
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

// how do implement?
abstract int GetCategory(Uri uri);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think of a solution:

1. Define a loop that traverses three access resources
2. Exit when a resource is found
3. Start with the first until you've tried all three

   ```
   private StreamResourceInfo GetSound(Uri uri)
   {
       var resource = default(StreamResourceInfo);
       var category = 0;
       while (category <3)
       {
           try
           {
               switch (category)
               {
                   //resource
                   case 0:
                       resource = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
                       break;
                   // content
                   case 1:
                       resource = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
                       break;
                   // source site
                   case 2:
                       resource = Application.GetRemoteStream(uri);
                       break;
                   default:
                       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
               }
           }
           catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("未找到截图音资源");
               break;
           }
           if (null == resource)
           {
               category++;
           }
           else
           {
               break;
           }
       }
       return resource;
   }
   ```